# How do I bind a Background property to a WriteableBitmap in code?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding

I'm trying to bind the Background property of a Border element to a property of type WriteableBitmap in code.

Being Image the WriteableBitmap, I'm trying the following with no success, thus, the border shows without any background:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = dataContext.Image;
myBorder.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundProperty, b);

dataContext.Image = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
dataContext.Image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `Image` is your property, but you can try like this:

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Path = new PropertyPath("Image"); // Image should be a public property in your datacontext
b.Source = dataContext;
myBorder.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundProperty, b);

dataContext.Image = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
dataContext.Image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
RaiseProperty("Image"); //raise property change
```